Unable to reopen YouTube iframe embed full screen after open-exit full screen mod fast
Whenever i try to open and exit youtube embed video in full screen mode fast, button full screen in youtube frame stop working even when i reload the page
It can only work if i close and reopen the page
This is the page code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<body>

    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kWi1beTiVig" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen"></iframe>
    <br />

</body>

Is there any solution for this?
I had already try to add attributes in iframe but nothing fix the problem

What device and browser are you testing on? I cannot reproduce in Chrome for Windows. Also is it possibly a hardware (glitch) issue instead of a Javascript code issue? Test on another device/OS.

I test on Chrome, Microsoft Edge on Windows, the only way to reproduce is using esc to exit right after click button expand and it happen after a few tries
